# Neptune severless freeable memory decreases day by day

Tags: amazon-neptune, neptune

I have a neptune severless instance that has been running perfectly fine scaling up and down as expected in accordance with the clear seasonality of reading and writing to it. In the past 6 weeks I have noticed a gradual decrease in the neptune freeable memory, which is leading to an increase in the number of NCUs it is using

Neptune gets about 5% of the traffic in the off peak hours compared to the peak hours. The freaable memory used to bounce back in the off peak hours, but has not been the case recently. There has been no changes to any of the reading or writing lambdas and they are running as they have been for months. I am using python lambdas and gremlin to query Neptune.

The NCU util:
[image]

The freeable memory:
[image]

The CPU util:
[image]

I am starting to run out of ideas to figure out what is causing this. This feels like a potential caching issue and I do have the 'neptune_lookup_cache' enabled. But the documentation is also a bit vague surrounding it and I have had it on durng November and December which were much busier and issue free.

I would greatly appreciate input or any direction from anyone that has had a similiar issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `neptune_lookup_cache` feature is only supported in the r5d instances and is not supported on the serverless instance types.  Even if enabled, that parameter would get ignored unless the correct instance type is there. For more info on how a lookup cache works, I would suggest this blog series on Neptune's caching features: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-1-accelerate-graph-query-performance-with-caching-in-amazon-neptune/

Freeable memory is the amount of RAM allocated for query execution.  As this goes down, it means that the requests to Neptune are requiring more and more memory to process.  This is generally seen in situations where a graph begins to grow in size and the associated queries are not written to avoid scaling with the size of the graph (query "frontier", or the amount of data that a query needs to process, grows with graph scale).  I would check your query processing times (if you are tracking those elsewhere) and see if those are also increasing over a given time period.  If they are, look for opportunities to tune queries to avoid scaling with the graph.  May not be possible if you are using queries that perform any sort of larger aggregations such as grouping or sorting.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it is much appreciated.

I am logging the query processing times and they have not increased, they have been running pretty consistently for the better part of a year. So I think it might not be the case in this instance, but I'm not dismissing it just yet. I will keep it in mind as I continue my investigation.

And thank you for the suggestion to look into the frontier issue. I am forseeing that data flowing into my graph will ramp up quite a bit in the future, so this is great to keep in mind as I build it out going into the future.

Comment: There's also a new engine (1.3.1.0) release that is currently being rolled out which optimizes how statistics are collected on serverless instances.  You may want to consider upgrading (when the release is available in your region) to see if this has any effect.  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/engine-releases-1.3.1.0.html. If that does not solve it, you may want to open a support case and see if someone from the engineering team can take a look.